# HTML5 Canvas: drawImage not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

This code is working in chrome, opera yandex and ie browsers, but failed to run on firefox.

"el" in the code is my image (stored like this `<img src="background.png"`).

```
fadeIn: function(el){
        var self = this;

        var alpha = 0;
        var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
            if (alpha < 1){
                self.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Lottery.Canvas.width, Lottery.Canvas.height );
                alpha += 0.01;
                self.ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
                self.ctx.drawImage(el, 0, 0);
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you could use a library with cross browser compatibility. This one is lightweight and mostly for image drawing/animation: http://iio.js.org/

Comment: Hit `F12` and check the console for errors, FF is not as forgiving as other browsers when it comes to JavaScript and this could well be a code error, but without the rest of the code I am but guessing.

Comment: No errors though, nothing just not drawing the image!

Comment: Need a testcase. The only relevant thing I remember is that data from other origins may not be drawn on canvas to prevent leaking the user's data.

Comment: FF behaves differently than Chrome when you do not include the `setInterval` second argument (time in ms) Chrome fires very quickly, while FF fires once then does nothing. I did not wait long to find out but well over a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems that matters to firefox,

1. setInterval need a interval value i set it to 1ms
2. Variable alpha is not defined. I defined it to 0.01 ( you might want to create a local variable, I have it as a globle)

Tested on FF. https://jsfiddle.net/rg1uyw1p/5/

```js
var editor = {
ctx : "",
fadeIn: function  (el){
        var self = this;
        var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
            if (alpha < 1){
                self.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Lottery.Canvas.width, Lottery.Canvas.height );
                alpha += 0.1;
                self.ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
                self.ctx.drawImage(el, 0, 0);
                console.log("ALPHA: " +  alpha);
            } else {
              console.log("CLEAR: " +  alpha);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        },1);
    },
};
Lottery = {};
alpha = 0.01;
Lottery.Canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
editor.ctx = Lottery.Canvas.getContext("2d");
editor.fadeIn(document.getElementById("img"));
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png?v=6f86a5fa447f">
<canvas id="canvas"  width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```